# NSException in table view core data

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsexception

Im developing an app that shows basic info from a coredata db,
I have the db saving info when hit save button,
but when I want to show the data in another view in a table, 
I get no errors, but an NSexeption>

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:    '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Contacts''
```

the data is saving correctly as I checked it in a sqlite graphical interface, but not showing in the table, with the above error,

how to fix it please?

my little project is in 
[here!](http://www.kadekamstaffs.com.au/CoreDataEnsaShowSup.zip)

thank you so much!

Comment: Your project wasnt found at that link you provided.

Comment: hi, yes sorry now the link is working , thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your `managedObjectContext` needs to come from the App Deleagte, in `ShowViewController` try:

```
    managedObjectContext = [(CoreDataEnsaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Right now, the context is coming form _context, which is NULL.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but is not clear to me where to change this call, thank you!